# STM32F412 CAN Mailbox Runs Full

Tags: stm32, can

I have a problem with the CAN communication on a custom board with STM32F412.

The problem is that the CAN mailboxes run full and CAN communication comes to a halt.

This happend with the transceiver in Normal mode as well as in Loopback mode.

This is the code I use for sending:

```c
if (HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(CAN_HANDLE) > 0)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef retVal = HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(CAN_HANDLE, &canMsg.header, canMsg.data, &canMailbox);

    switch (retVal) // used for counting errors
    {
    case HAL_OK:
        ++halOkHits; // counts up
        break;
    case HAL_ERROR:
        ++halErrorHits; // stays zero
        break;
    case HAL_BUSY:
        ++halBusyHits; // stays zero
        break;
    case HAL_TIMEOUT:
        ++halTimeoutHits; // stays zero
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    ++halAppMailboxFullCounter; // counts up; graph is shown below

    HAL_CAN_AbortTxRequest(CAN_HANDLE, CAN_TX_MAILBOX0);
}
```

The following graph shows the value of `halAppMailboxFullCounter`.

[image: halAppMailboxFullCounter graph]

All messages are sent every second.

A connected PCAN-Adapter shows a bus load of ~30% with a peak at 37%.

For our case it's OK to drop some messages, that's why I clear the first mailbox in case none is free. This is done to free the mailboxes in case of an erratic bus.

The PriorityQueue feature of the CAN transceiver is turned off, so all messages should be treated equally.

Does anyone have an explanation for the fact the every ten seconds (the steps in the graph are ten seconds wide) the mailbox runs full for a few cycles?

Also, why does the occurrence of full mailboxes decrease over time? Has onyone seen this before?

**Edit to address some issues Jeroen3 brought up**:

- The reason for only aborting one mailbox war to only skip the one message that might be stuck (no ACK on the bus) ... But this appoach has so many assumptions in it that I always wanted to investigate further ... It might not be the right thing to do. However, the graph looks the same if I abort all three mailboxes every time there is no free one.
- The automatic retransmit feature is disabled.

**Edit on new observations**:

- The same graph shows if the CAN transceiver is set to Loopback mode.

**Solved one issue**:
We solved the issue with the communication getting stuck by overhaulung the cabling. ... This does not change the full mailboxes drawing a stairs pattern ... I will go back to the stm32f4 reference manual and rethink our sending approach as Jeroen3 suggested.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: Why do you disable automatic retransmit feature?

Answer (score 1):

You only have three transmit mailboxes.
That means that you can set only three frames pending for transmit by the bxCAN controller.  Others have to wait in software buffers.

If you did not implement the error handlers of CAN bus and cancel transmission when they fail (eg: bus full, no acknowledge or arbitation failure) you will eventually use up all mailboxes.
The hardware does not provide a timeout function, you have to keep track of possible mailbox timeouts yourself.

Your code only aborts transmit of box 0 when all mailboxes are full, so your behavior is not strange.

Also, if you did enabled the automatic retransmit feature, mailboxes will never free automatically until transmit is successfully completed.

[image]

---

Also careful, there are only two FIFO's of 3 object deep for receiving. Without fitlers only one is used. And this can be overrun these if you some have interrupt jitter and high bus speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into the error handlers and how to use them. ... In the next few days. ... I will also add some of the issues you brought up to my initial question.

Comment: Sounds like a mediocre CAN controller... 20 years old legacy 8 bit MCUs have more hardware buffers than that. Out of curiosity, is this some crap STM32 has inherited from STM8 or what's the reason? Industry standard nowadays is some ~32 mailboxes and >8 messages rx FIFO.

Comment: @Lundin they call it bxCAN, the STM8 beCAN it looks the same. And it is very mediocre. Granted, the core it's running with is a lot faster, so you can just extend it by software. But yeah... mediocre.